# Why My CSS animation is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, css-animations

I am trying to animate my Cube(dice) when user presses the button and execute dice case. My Code works perfect but animation does not work. I am using timeout but it's not working.

HTML

Cube is dice, Side is sides of the cube

```
<div class="cube">
        <div class="side top"></div>
        <div class="side bottom"></div>
        <div class="side front"></div>
        <div class="side back"></div>
        <div class="side right"></div>
        <div class="side left"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Roll" id="roll">
```

CSS

```
.cube
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(193deg) rotateY(269deg);
    animation: rolling 4s;
}
.anim {
    animation: rolling 3s;
}
@keyframes rolling {
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(455deg) rotateY(455deg);
    }
    
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("roll").addEventListener("click", function () {
    side = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    console.log(`dic Case : ${side}`);
    document.getElementsByClassName("cube")[0].classList.add("anim");
    setTimeout(() => {
        roll(side);
    }, 4000);
})
```

Also, If you can also improve some of the design in my CSS please do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

css code

```css
.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: red;
}

.anim {
  animation: rolling 3s;
}

@keyframes rolling {
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(455deg) rotateY(455deg);
  }

}
```

javaScript code

```js
document.getElementById("roll").addEventListener("click", function () {
  side = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  console.log(`dic Case : ${side}`);
  document.getElementsByClassName("cube")[0].classList.add("anim");
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("cube")[0].classList.remove('anim')
  }, 3000);
})
```

Comment: thanks for replied, But How it's work and what is problem in my code, when i remove animation code in cube it's completely working

Comment: Yes, right, But then I think working only one click, not working from second click about button.

Comment: Because after one clicked button, then exists anim class to element.